# Dynamic Dictionary Field Names

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary with dynamic names ( m['field1'], m['field2'], etc).  But I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

```
index = 0
for i in results:
        metrics['users']['total']['month' + str(index)] = results[index][1]
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: Could you show us the value of `results` and `metrics` before the above code runs?

Comment: metrics = {}     and results = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a dictionary doesn't have a specific key (e.g. when `metrics` is empty and thus doesn't have the `users` key), reading the dictionary by that key (i.e. `metrics['users']`) is an error. I'm not sure exactly what you want, but the following code runs fine:

```
metrics = {'users': {'total': {}}}
results = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
index = 0
for i in results:
    metrics['users']['total']['month' + str(index)] = results[index][1]
    index = index + 1
```